# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.experimental'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I have sklearn installed but still I have error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.experimental'

when trying to run Jupyter notebook from [Imputing missing values before building an estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/impute/plot_missing_values.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-impute-plot-missing-values-py).
I'm using pip for installation without any virtual environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just realized my pip version of sklearn is `20.03` while latest is `scikit-learn v0.21.3`

I've upgraded sklearn with (in CMD):

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn --user --upgrade pip
```

I've had permission error using standard upgrade command. 
I had to restart Jupyter notebook kernel with clear output, run cells again, run again (in first cell in Jupyter Notebook):

```
%matplotlib inline
```

and than it was working.

Comment: Just had the same issue. Thanks for posting! +1

Comment: @Alex I'm glad it was helpful :)

Comment: How exactly do u run this line? i get a syntax error putting this in a cell

Comment: @JohnnyThomas better fundamental knowledge could be beneficial. But I've added notes. First line is installing update so you need to put it in command line (CMD in Windows). Second is executed in Jupyter cell.